# Merge dataframes, add/update field

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, merge

I'm trying to merge/join two dataframes with `pandas`, on person_id.
If a match is found, its should add or update the email field. 
It should not create new rows, that dosnt exists in Table_A.

Table_A

```
+-----------+-----------------+------+
| person_id |      email      | lang |
+-----------+-----------------+------+
|         1 |                 | EN   |
|         2 | tes2@foo.com    | FR   |
|         3 | tes3@barbar.com | DK   |
+-----------+-----------------+------+
```

Table_B

```
+-----------+--------------+------+
| person_id |    email     | kids |
+-----------+--------------+------+
|         1 | tes1@foo.com |    2 |
|         2 | tes2@foo.com |    0 |
|         3 | tes3@foo.com |    0 |
|         4 | tes4@foo.com |    1 |
+-----------+--------------+------+
```

The result I'm looking for is

```
+-----------+--------------+------+------+
| person_id |    email     | kids | lang |
+-----------+--------------+------+------+
|         1 | tes1@foo.com |    2 | EN   |
|         2 | tes2@foo.com |    0 | FR   |
|         3 | tes3@foo.com |    0 | DK   |
|         4 | tes5@foo.com |    1 |      |
+-----------+--------------+------+------+
```

I have tried with

```
df_merged=pd.merge(Table_A,Table_B,on=["person_id"], how="left")
```

This gives me the correct fields, but also makes a email_x and email_y field. I just want one email field.

Comment: I think that you have to use `.join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's somewhat of an ad hoc solution...

Merge both the dataframes and add suffixes.

```
dfNew = df.merge(df1, left_index=True, right_index=True,how='outer', suffixes=('_y', ''))

     #result
     person_id_y       email_y  lang  person_id         email   kids
            1             None   EN         1    tes1@foo.com     2
            2     tes2@foo.bar   FR         2    tes2@foo.com     0
            3  tes2@barbar.com   DK         3    tes3@foo.com     0
          NaN              NaN  NaN         4    tes4@foo.com     1
```

Then just filter for the columns you want

```
dfNew = dfNew[['person_id','email','kids','lang']]

person_id         email  kids lang
        1  tes1@foo.com     2   EN
        2  tes2@foo.com     0   FR
        3  tes3@foo.com     0   DK
        4  tes4@foo.com     1  NaN
```